# Loop through code and highlight row. Return only first two finds

Tags: vba, excel

I've written code to loop through a range for a specific value. If the value equals "123" then highlight the entire row green. However, I only want it to highlight the very first two matches it finds and stop there. Many thanks.

```
Sub Macro3()

    Sheets("XYZ").Select

    Dim rng As Range

    Sheets("XYZ").Select
    Set rng = Range("L2:L10000")
    For Each cell In rng    
        If cell.Value = "123" Then    
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4    
        End If                  
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Create a counter variable and for each find increase the counter by 1.  When it reaches your desired count (2 in this case), exit the sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better if you avoid using `Select` and other relatives, instead use referenced `Objects`, `Sheets` and `Range`s.
Also, you can search for the last row with data in Column L instead of just looping through row 10000.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro3()

Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim counter As Integer, LastRow As Long

With Sheets("XYZ")
    ' find last row at Column "L"
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = .Range("L2:L" & LastRow)

    For Each cell In Rng
        If cell.Value = "123" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
        If counter >= 2 Then Exit For
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Macro3()

Sheets("XYZ").Select

Dim rng As Range
dim count as integer

'Set the range in column D to loop through
Sheets("XYZ").Select
Set rng = Range("L2:L10000")
For Each cell In rng    
    If cell.Value = "123" Then    
        cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4    
        count = count + 1
    End If
    if count >= 2 Then exit For                
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering lets you avoid looping through cells

Assuming row 1 has header, you can try:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim counter As Integer

With Sheets("XYZ")
    With .Range("L1",  .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "L" cells from row 1 (header) down to last not empty row
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="123" '<--| filter referenced range on its first (and only) column with "123"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell gets filtered
            For Each cell In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| loop through filtered cells, skipping header
                cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                counter = counter + 1 '<--| update counter
                If counter = 2 Then Exit For '<--| exit at 2nd iteration
            Next cell
        End If
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code with some addition:

```
        Sub Macro3()

        Sheets("XYZ").Select

        Dim rng As Range
        greenrows = 0
        Sheets("XYZ").Select
        Set rng = Range("b2:b10000")
            For Each cell In rng

              If cell.Value = "123" Then
                 If greenrows = 2 Then Exit Sub
                 cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                 greenrows = greenrows + 1
              End If
           Next

      End Sub
```